# How to give a colour to particular div by selecting a colour in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, paintcomponent

I am an intermediate in javascript. I am making  an app for children .. I am developing in it  HTML5/javascript.  My app motive is to select the letter and practice them by sketching the outline of letters..
Here is my app design in below picture[image]

In the app I want to select the color of the required one from the colour given in pencil and paint in the outline of A. and I have to erase with the eraser given..
I had almost finished the app except the colouring part..
Please anyone help and guide me how to do this..
I just want to know  how to make this to colour outline by selecting the colours.. if there any code available or demo available please tell  me about that.
Experts shed light on this problem

Comment: are you using canvas to draw?

Comment: @intuitivepixel yes I want to yse the canvas but when i try to create the "A" in canvas i failed in creation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Revised answer based on changed request]**

Here’s how to let the child draw anywhere within a bounding box around the letter

First, define the area that the drawing will be restricted to.

Any drag-draws outside the drawable area won't be visible.

```
    // define the drawable area
    var minX=60;
    var maxX=250;
    var minY=140;
    var maxY=380;
```

Then in mousemove, draw only if the mouse is inside that drawable area:

```
        if(mouseX>minX && mouseX<maxX && mouseY>minY && mouseY<maxY){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
            ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tAkAy/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:637px;
        height:477px;
    }
    #canvas,#bkImg{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #canvas{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.lineWidth=25;
    ctx.lineCap="round";

    // define the drawable area
    // any drag-draws outside the drawable area won't be visible
    var minX=60;
    var maxX=250;
    var minY=140;
    var maxY=380;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
        if(!isDown){return;}
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        if(mouseX>minX && mouseX<maxX && mouseY>minY && mouseY<maxY){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
            ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        startX=mouseX;
        startY=mouseY;
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="bkImg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/game1.png" width=637 height=477>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=637 height=477></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Original answer ]**

*How to draw  lines on a canvas in a selected color*

[image]

Here is some code for you to start with.

The important points are:

- Mousedown starts a line and sets it beginning point
- Mouseup ends a line and sets its endpoint.  This is a permanent line.
- Mousemove draws a *temporary* line until the user releases the mouse.
- All permanent lines must be redrawn when a temporary line is being drawn because the canvas must be erased to create the “moving” temporary line.

Html canvas draws a line using it's context like this:

```
    function drawLine(line){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line.x1,line.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(line.x2,line.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

To set/change the line color, you set the context's strokeStyle:

```
    context.strokeStyle="blue";
```

To erase all drawings on the canvas, you use context's clearRect:

```
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

If you're not used to specifying hit zones, it's pretty simple.

- Specify a bounding box (top-left and bottom-right) of the area you might hit (eg. the blue crayon)
- Then if the mouse clicks inside that bounding box, you have a hit.

The canvas is layered over the game image and all lines are being drawn on the canvas, not the image.

The rest is just straightforward javascript stuff.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/G6eWn/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:637px;
        height:477px;
    }
    #canvas,#bkImg{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #canvas{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.lineWidth=25;
    ctx.lineCap="round";

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    var lines=[];

    var eraser={x:446,y:413,right:516,bottom:475};

    var pens=[
        {x:240,y:413,right:275,bottom:475,color:"red"},
        {x:276,y:413,right:308,bottom:475,color:"green"},
        {x:309,y:413,right:341,bottom:475,color:"orange"},
        {x:342,y:413,right:375,bottom:475,color:"blue"},
        {x:376,y:413,right:412,bottom:475,color:"yellow"},
        {x:412,y:413,right:447,bottom:475,color:"pink"},
    ];


    function selectPenColor(x,y){
        for(var i=0;i<pens.length;i++){
            var pen=pens[i];
            if(x>=pen.x && x<=pen.right && y>=pen.y && y<=pen.bottom){
                ctx.strokeStyle=pen.color;
                drawLines();
                return(true);
            }
        }
        return(false);
    }

    function drawLines(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            drawLine(lines[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawLine(line){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line.x1,line.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(line.x2,line.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function selectEraser(x,y){
        if(x>=eraser.x && x<=eraser.right && y>=eraser.y && y<=eraser.bottom){
            lines=[];
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            return(true);
        }
        return(false);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // select a pen color or erase
      // if so, don't start a line
      if(selectPenColor(mouseX,mouseY)){return;}
      if(selectEraser(mouseX,mouseY)){return;}

      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      isDown=false;
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      lines.push({x1:startX,y1:startY,x2:mouseX,y2:mouseY});
      drawLines();

    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
        handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){

        if(!isDown){return;}
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        drawLines();

        drawLine({x1:startX,y1:startY,x2:mouseX,y2:mouseY});

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="bkImg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/game1.png" width=637 height=477>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=637 height=477></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It helped me. But I want to reduce the size of canvas only to letter 'A' so that I can colour only inside A not outside of A.. Additioonally I am using letter A as a seperate image.. I change the canvas size and do it in your I example it works partialy.. please give me a way to paint only "image A".. Thanks Mark

Comment: When you say "only inside the A", do you mean that if the child goes outside the lines of the A that the pen stop drawing until the child goes back inside the lines of the A.  Or do you mean the canvas should be a square the same width/height as the A and the child can draw anywhere in that smaller canvas--even if they draw outside the lines of the A.

Comment: I mean the first one that  if the child goes outside the lines of the A that the pen stop drawing until the child goes back inside the lines of the A.

Comment: Here's a modified version of the game where the pen will draw color only within the letter A.  The key is that the letter A is drawn on the canvas.  Everything on the canvas is transparent except the letter A.  Then the context's globalCompositeOperation is set to "source-atop".  **This causes any drawings by the child to only occur within the non-transparent pixels of the letter A.**  Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/44Hds/

Comment: thanks for your help.... I tried it with in my windows app but i still cant draw thecolour in A... the letter A is not get painting.. So I go your 2nd way that you mentioned in your comment. I want the   canvas should be a square the same width/height as the A and the child can draw anywhere in that smaller canvas when the child goes out of the canvas it should not draw outside of the letter .kindly give your mail id plss.

Comment: ;p  Ok, I revised my answer to let the child draw anywhere inside the bounding box of the letter image. Note the canvas is the same size as the background picture.  But coloring is restricted to a rectangular area around the letter.  If different letters have different bounding areas, you can adjust minX, maxX, minY, maxY. Here's also a link to the revised code: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tAkAy/